# Issue Creation date is not commit date as expected

Tags: sonarqube

English is not my first language, and I am a bit rusty, so please bear with me.

When browsing the Sonar analysis for my project, I have the following seemingly incorrect data displayed: the creation date of the issue is not the commit date for this date, and I would like to understand why. It so happens that April 29 at 9:35 is the date of the last analysis on that branch.

[image: issue with creation date different from commit date]

My code is managed with git and hosted on GitLab. Sonarqube server is at version 7.9.2.30863.

I made some research and found the following: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/issues/#header-5.
As far I understand the above page says that all created issues have a creation date equals to the commit date, except if one of the following conditions is true:

- first analysis of a project or branch. More on that below. Let me move the rest out of the way first.
- When the rule is new in the profile (a brand new rule activated or a rule that was deactivated and is now activated). The quality profile used for this analysis was not modified

[image: quality profile]

- When SonarQube has just been upgraded (because rule implementations could be smarter now). I know I did not upgrade the server. However, it is difficult for me to prove that the server was not upgraded by someone else. I checked the logs, and all I can say is that the Sonar Qube server was last restarted on 2021/04/26, so a few days before the first ‘faulty’ analysis. Since I believe that an upgrade would force a restart, I can assume this condition I out of the way too.
- When the rule is external. I do not know what an external rule is. It seems to be linked to the configuration found under Administration > General Settings > External analyzers. However, it is all empty, so I believe I use no external analyzer, hence no external rules that are checked during an analysis.

Back to the first condition: ‘first analysis of a project or branch.’. This is now the most plausible explanation since all the other conditions are out of the way.
Sonar does not provide much history for short-lived branches, so I had to check my continuous integration pipelines to find out when the previous analysis was on that branch. I found a successful execution a few weeks ago (2021-04-09). Since it was more than a few days ago, could it be that the results of that analysis were somehow purged and that the analysis that took place on April 29 was somehow a ‘first analysis’ again? How to check that?

Conclusion: I still do not know why the date on that issue(and some others too) is wrong. All 'faulty' issues are located on the same file. I would gladly welcome any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the old issue was just merged into the branch you are currently analyzing?

I had a situation like this:

1. Checkout feature A branch in January 2021, chip away at it slowly
2. Checkout feature B branch in February 2021 - This one contains the issue merge feature B onto main in March 2021
3. Complete work on feature A, run sonarqube analysis
4. Merge in main, which contains feature B, run sonarqube analysis
5. Issue from feature B is reported as being created today instead of March 2021

If you were to merge Feature A back to main and then run analysis on main, the issue from feature B would have the correct date, but any new issues from feature A would be dated as per the analysis date.

sonarqube-9.3.0.51899